# How to get/refresh an OAuth2 token using the new Google APIs Auth dll?

Tags: google-api, dotnetopenauth, google-api-dotnet-client

We've been using the Google APIs OAuth2 dll to do our auth token refreshes.  The process often fails and I'm looking to update it to the new Google APIs Auth dll.  The Google APIs OAuth2 dll is considered obsolete mentioned [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Authentication/).

[Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/) is the new dll but I can't find an example on how to use it.  Anyone been able to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in our [OAuth2 wiki page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) which contains details on how to use the OAuth2 flows in Windows Phone, Windows 8 applications, ASP.NET MVC and regular .NET 4 applications.

You should also take a look in our [samples repository](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples) for sample code that works.

Last thing - please consider subscribe to our [announcements blog](http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/), for more news and updates about the library.